# Crash: app crash on row click. Crashlytics error : SIGABRT ABORT

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

My ios app running ok on all the devices.  It shows crash On iphone 6plus original device only.

Not getting exact issue. On Crashlytics we get issue report online, with this error. Below is a error log.

```
 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1864c3014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18658b450 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x186437400 abort + 140
3  libsystem_c.dylib              0x18640b3b8 __assert_rtn + 220
4  Metal                          0x189b1c3a4 MTLReportFailure + 780
5  Metal                          0x189af9c48 -[MTLTextureDescriptorInternal validateWithDevice:] + 568
6  AGXMetalA8                     0x1a13efe14 (Missing)
7  QuartzCore                     0x18a830104 allocate_drawable_private(unsigned int, unsigned int, id<MTLDevice>, MTLPixelFormat, MTLTextureRotation, bool, bool, bool, unsigned int, CGColorSpace*, _CAImageQueue*) + 320
8  QuartzCore                     0x18a82fcf8 -[CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] + 1492
9  VectorKit                      0x19358fbc0 -[MetalLayer _updateDrawable] + 68
10 VectorKit                      0x19358fc64 -[MetalLayer onTimerFired:] + 56
11 VectorKit                      0x193221834 -[VKMapView onTimerFired:] + 176
12 VectorKit                      0x193582dbc -[GGLDisplayLink _displayLinkFired:] + 84
13 QuartzCore                     0x18a74af24 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch(unsigned long long) + 44
14 QuartzCore                     0x18a74add0 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 444
15 IOKit                          0x187762094 IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18748ae50 __CFMachPortPerform + 180
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1874a3218 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 56
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1874a29cc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 436
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1874a04b0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1840
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1873ce2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
21 GraphicsServices               0x188e82198 GSEventRunModal + 180
22 UIKit                          0x18d4157fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
23 UIKit                          0x18d410534 UIApplicationMain + 208
24 SafeSide                       0x1000d7998 main (main.m:14)
25 libdispatch.dylib              0x1863b15b8 (Missing)
```

Edit:
Did select row's code:
@try

```
 {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        MonitorVC *monitor = Init_VCforStoryId(@"MonitorVC");
        monitor.monitorPassed = [arrMonitorList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:monitor animated:YES];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception handle: %@",exception.reason);
    }
```

Comment: show code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I have added the code. PLZ help .

Comment: It works on all devices and simulator devices . Except the iphone 6 plus. I don't know how. ! plz help

Comment: Try to run it by adding exception breakpoint and see exactly where it is crashing or try to get crash log.

Comment: According to apple developer forum thread, the problem may be in zero size of layer or IOSurface is nil https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/26278

Comment: @SachinAmrale An exception breakpoint will not catch SIGABRT.

Comment: @Esha You shouldn't have a generic catch-and-continue exception handler like in your `@try/@catch` code above.   A thrown NSException is an unrecoverable error in iOS.

Comment: Yes. @bbum . But unable to fetch the issue. means the point of the issue too.

Comment: @Esha Did you succeed in fixing this crash? I have the exact same crash reported in Crashlytics (on iphone 7 plus) and in iTunesConnect/Xcode (on iPhone 6s plus), but I can't reproduce it either on physical device nor simulator...